# Passing Puppeteer log result into contenteditable field (non-input)?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

It took a while to find out how to pass value into form input using this code:

```
await page.$eval('input[name=wc_name]', (el, name) => { el.value = name; }, result.name);
```

But my question is, how do I pass the value into non-input (contenteditable)?

I know how to do it with manual text:

```
await page.type("[class='ql-editor ql-blank']", 'mymanualpricesethere');
```

I'm trying to pass `result.price`

I have tried:

```
await page.type("[class='ql-editor ql-blank']", (el, price) => { el.value = price; }, result.price);
```

But it doesn't pass (I see blank)

Need some help.

Comment: Why not await page.type("[class='ql-editor ql-blank']", result.price) ?

Comment: it worked! thanks! Post it as an answer so I could accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not await page.type("[class='ql-editor ql-blank']", result.price) ?